# How to modify property of the pseudo classes in Chakra theme config?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

Since Chakra's colorScheme is based on one colour config and the fact that the colour of the brand is dark too, some elements of the page are not readable in dark mode.

I can manually define the secondary colour in each element. However, I'd like to define these changes in the themeConfig.

However, I'm unable to figure how to style pseudo-classes.

Example :

This works

```
<Tab
    _selected={{
        color: 'white',
        borderBottom: '2px solid #54b039',
    }}
>
    {value.text}
</Tab>
```

However using this themeConfig does not

```
const theme = extendTheme(
    {
        colors: {
            primary: {
                50: '#1f244333',
                100: '#1f244344',
                200: '#1f244388',
                300: '#1f244399',
                400: '#1f2443AA',
                500: '#1f2443EE',
                600: '#1f2443FF',
                700: '#1f2443DD',
                800: '#1f2443EE',
                900: '#1f2443FF',
            },
            secondary: '#5ab03b',
            background: '#f8f8f6',
        },
        components: {
            Tab: {
                _selected: {
                    color: 'white',
                    borderBottom: '2px solid #54b039',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    withDefaultColorScheme({
        colorScheme: 'primary',
    })
)
```